# Is 'all of a' a determiner?

Tags: determiners

> "Welcome back, Mr. Potter, welcome back." 
>  
>        Harry didn't know what to say. Everyone was looking at
>   him. The old woman with the pipe was puffing on it without realizing
>   it had gone out. Hagrid was beaming. 
>        Then there
>   was a great scraping of chairs and the next moment, Harry found
>   himself shaking hands with everyone in the Leaky Cauldron. 
>  
>        "Doris Crockford, Mr. Potter, can't believe I'm meeting
>   you at last." 
>        "So proud, Mr. Potter, I'm just so
>   proud." 
>        "Always wanted to shake your hand –– I'm
>   **all of a flutter**." 
>  (Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone)

There seem to be not a few ‘all of a Noun’ phrases –– all of a dither, all of a heap, all of a jump, all of a muddle. Is ‘all of a’ a kind of determiner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In these constructions, *all* is an adverb = “entirely”. The remaining *of a Y* piece is an ordinary prepositional phrase with adjectival force. The collocation ascribes the condition expressed by the object of *of* to the noun modified.

So to say “I'm all of a flutter” means “I’m completely in a state of flutter”.

I’ve never encountered the construction without *all*, but it is closely related to  the ‘genitive of quality’, which ascribes a quality rather than a condition—*a man **of** means, a woman **of** tact*. The AmE equivalent employs *in*—*I'm all **in** a flutter/muddle/dither/&c*—and this ***is*** used without *all*: *She’s always in a muddle about something.*